# What can I do to see only the logical values in the MOSFET input?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, protection, thermistor, logic-level

[image: Schematic]

(Animated GIF of the simulation is [here](https://s9.gifyu.com/images/screen-capture-4.gif))

This is a simple circuit that makes the MOSFET turn off, as the temperature of the NTC thermistor rises.

As you increase the temperature in the diagram, the value in the voltmeter decreases.

5 volts--->4 volts--->3 volts--->2.5 volts ...

But I don't want voltage values between 5 volts and 0 volts. The value read on the voltmeter should be either logic high or logic low.
How do I do this?

Comment: do you want this only on Falstad? or for design purposes? you can use a comparator if it's for a design...

Comment: Schmitt trigger.

Comment: This is from myself, so you need to interpret it by researching the key-words. Logic is a different "domain" from the "voltage level". And, those can be mapped by "symbolic" association, doesn't matter what voltage. Google search of "logic level detection" suggested many and [this](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/logic-level) and [that](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/logic-levels/all) are the first and second pop-up-s.

Comment: Do you want to change what you *see*, or do you want to change what *happens*?

Comment: CircuitJS (the actual name of this simulator) has "logic outputs" that will show L or H instead of showing the voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Using the threshold of a FET as a comparator is a very questionable design practice. The threshold voltage can vary quite a bit, even for a specific FET. It’s impossible to guarantee a consistent input to output transition.

The reason you don’t see a sharp transition between output-high and low also relates to the FET near-threshold behavior. As the FET gate voltage crosses over the threshold, the FET is being biased in its linear mode, so the output makes a gradual transition as the temperature increases, rather than the sharp transition you’re looking for.

Strongly suggest instead that you add a comparator to the circuit, like an LM339 or similar. Falstad has a comparator model in its library. Then you can set a precise threshold that will snap the output state to a definitive level.

One more tip about Falstad: you can create a link to your simulation and add it to your description, so that other people can run it as well.

Related: [Why is there a resistor in this circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/564091/why-is-there-a-resistor-in-this-circuit/564092#564092)